# removed column from postresql, but django doesn't see it

Tags: django, postgresql, migration

I removed the column from postresql database by using sql statement (alter table table_name drop column if exists column_name); It removed it... But django model doesn't see it... I tried "syncdb", but it is deprecated, so no more functional, tried makemigrations and migrate, but it doesn't change models in django... It should be quite simple task? Since it should be normal to change database (if not primary or foreign keys)... but nothing I tried works for me and there are seems no answer for this questions... fake migrations wouldn't be good for database, and turning off django changing database is not an option also? And because I have django and postresql not synced, I have filter fault which comes up... Any help? Thank you!

Comment: as I understand makemigrations and migrate should sync the data in postgresql and django, but somehow django in cmd (It is windows environment) tells me there are no changes in database, but I know I removed the column and this column is not present in database anymore... Any reason for such strange behavior of django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does not look into database when you run `makemigrations`

It looks up for changes in actual [Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/) that you have

You should not manually delete columns from database, if you remove column from Django model and afterwards run ( makemigrations and migrate ) it would be removed in database too.

Look up in your source for model for your table and remove field that is no longer there

Comment: Also it would be beneficiary for you to check out Django tutorial
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: So, I started from the wrong side... I probably should bring the column back? Because when I delete this field from model at the current state, and try to runserver I run into filter fault... Thank you. I will try your advice.

Comment: You would probably want to add that field back as you want your migrations to pass successfully :).  You maybe also need to remove that field on places used through application.

Comment: Oh... my gosh... I just went through the quite bad time... Some other forums suggested to dumpdata and then loaddata... I could dump it, but couldn't load it back due to this fault... I found it dumped my virtual environment :(... But I recovered now... I tried to delete this column from django.. but still have the same mistake, while I am trying to migrate changes... it sais: (admin.E116) the value of 'list_filter[5]' refers to 'prefix', which does not refer to a field.

Comment: I did as it was recommended... recover column 'prefix' in postgresql, run migrations (just in case) and checked if server is working... it was working with prefix running through some if else statements... Then I deleted the line with the field prefix and tried migrations... it gave me this above fault... Sorry for so much writing!

Comment: Could it be that my model, which is in sublime, not connected to actual model in django? I remember I ran inspectdb and copied the structure of some tables into the model file...

Comment: I have mentioned previously that you probably need to check your code too. It seems you are mentioning column that you have removed ( prefix) inside django admin (admin.py) file

Comment: but every changes i make they do change the data in database... and server works perfectly fine... i.e. receiving and sending data into the database...

Comment: Thank you! It worked... They are (postgresql and django)detached from each other in terms of actual changes. But iklinac is right... The changes must be made first in django and after you can delete column in postresql, so this way changes do not affect the actual work of the server... The source of my mistake was admin file where I should also delete fields, which I forgot to do... Dumb me! And django was actually saying to telling me that all the time! I hope it helps to somebody! Thank you, iklinac!